# Weirdest way of displaying "LaTeX" (Contest)

Tags: fun

LaTeX is a program for making beautiful documents with elaborate code.
As we all know, typesetting the name of LaTeX itself by using the command `\LaTeX` produces a pretty weird symbol combination.

But we can do better than that, right?

What's your weirdest way to display something that can be read as "LaTeX"?

Comment: LaTeX ist _not_ a programming language and _not_ a programm. It is only a macro package, no more no less. The program is `tex`, `pdftex`, `luatex`, or `xetex ...`

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. Excuse me. But if those examples are examples of programs, then what is the name of the programming language?

Comment: Well, there's always `\(\Lambda\alpha\Tau\epsilon\Chi\)`...

Comment: The language is always `TeX` or combined with `Lua` when using `luatex`